# How to prevent "Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?" alert on form submission?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple html form with few fields in it.

I wanted to make sure that user gets an alert message when he is trying to leave the page. So I added the script on the page which will run whenever user is trying to navigate away from this page.

But I am also getting this alert message when user is trying to submit the form. I dont want this alert message when user is saving the form.

Please help.

Below is some sample code.

```
<html>
    <head>

    <script>
        function verifyexit() { return 'Are you sure ?'; }           window.onbeforeunload = verifyexit;
    </script>       
</head>
<body>
        Go to <a href="b.html"> another page </a> 
        <form action="c.html">
            name : <input type="text" name="name" value=""/> <br>
            email : <input type="text" name="email" value=""/> <br>
            <input type="submit" value="save"/>
        </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[stackoverflow reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119289/how-to-show-the-are-you-sure-you-want-to-navigate-away-from-this-page-when-ch?rq=1)

To turn it on:

```
window.onbeforeunload = "Are you sure you want to leave?";
```

To turn it off:

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```

Bear in mind that this isn't a normal event - you can't bind to it in the standard way.

To check for values? That depends on your validation framework.

In jQuery this could be something like (very basic example):

```
$('input').change(function() {
    if( $(this).val() != "" )
        window.onbeforeunload = "Are you sure you want to leave?";
});
```

[With JQuery](http://jonstjohn.com/node/23) this stuff is pretty easy to do. Since you can **bind** to sets.

Its NOT enough to do the onbeforeunload, you want to only trigger the navigate away if someone started editing stuff.

To make this work in Chrome and Safari, you would have to do it like this

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;

    var msg = "Sure you want to leave?";

    // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
    if (e) {
        e.returnValue = msg;
    }

    // For Safari
    return msg;
};
```

**This is the general rule in reference**

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  e = e || window.event;

  // For IE<8 and Firefox prior to version 4
  if (e) {
    e.returnValue = 'Any string';
  }

  // For Chrome, Safari, IE8+ and Opera 12+
  return 'Any string';
};
```

[reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload)

Comment: `you can't bind to it in the standard way` Please clarify.

Comment: Note that setting a custom text is now not possible, as of 2016: https://chromestatus.com/feature/5349061406228480

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<form action="c.html" onsubmit="window.onbeforeunload=function(){}">
```

Comment: He stated in his question that he wanted the onbeforeunload to execute in all instances EXCEPT when the form is being submitted, so this goes to his specification.

Comment: same...so deleted my ans and +1 urs. @Ashish also see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FEvkK/ for another working example.

Comment: @Sean Johnson. Very strange. I could see your example working correctly. Even Kshitij's example is working properly. I just copy pasted the same stuff at my end and its still not working. I tried both your and Kshitij's versions.

Comment: this has a lot to do with compatability what are the tested version pleas?

Comment: @shareef. I am testing on IE7

Comment: I believe some browsers will still pop the message if window.onbeforeunload is anything other than 'null'. An empty function qualifies as a value using this criteria. Just set window.onbeforeunload = null here and you should be good

Comment: @anything IE5-8 and FireFox1-3.5 need the `window.onbeforeunload` to be set to `null`, setting it to `function(){}` (like this answer) won't work for those older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(window).bind("beforeUnload", verify);
$("form").submit(function (){
    $(window).unbind("beforeUnload");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://cfsilence.com/blog/client/index.cfm/2009/10/12/jQuery-Method-To-Prompt-A-User-To-Save-Changes-Before-Leaving-Page

I added another bit to the function:

```
 $('#submitButton').click(function () {
        isDirty = false;
});
```

Just so the form doesn't ask for validation when you want to submit it :)

I hope this helps

Note: You could also do something like $("input[type=submit]") if you don't like to depend on a common naming (else your submit button needs to be called submitButton)