# Stylize Javascript Exit Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, popup, exit

I'm trying to create and stylize exit popup (borders, background, font) that appears when user tries to leave the page. This is an example of script:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){

 $(function() {
   alert("My message");
 });

return ' ';

});
```

Alert box is displayed first and user has to click OK so the exit confirmation box could appear. This DOES work since it prevents exit confirmation box to appear immediately on top. Confirmation box message:

```
This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved. (Leave page / Stay on page)
```

But I'm know it is impossible to change the style of alertbox so I tried with jQuery UI dialog():

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){

$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
});

return ' ';
});
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work as expected as well since dialog doesn't have same functionality as alert. Dialog appears simultaneously with confirmation box.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try disabling the native exit modal by nullifying the `onbeforeunload` event.

`window.onbeforeunload = null` [As explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183682/how-to-prevent-are-you-sure-you-want-to-navigate-away-from-this-page-alert-on)

This would mean you have to prevent default event behavior when navigating away from the current page so that you can display your custom modal with your modal engine of choice.

Comment: I'm reading answers on the reference link you posted, but I don't need to nullify default confirmation "Leave Page/Stay on Page" window because there is no input on the (static) page.

I use 'beforeunload' to prevent users from leaving the page before I display the exit popup. This is done by displaying regular alert box FIRST, then the confirmation box appears.

Is there a way to emulate dialog box behavior like alert box behavior? I want the dialog box to appear BEFORE confirmation box (Leave Page/Stay on Page) so I could apply the desired style that I can't apply to regular alert box?

Comment: Right. What I meant was: if the action that is taking your users away from the page is a click event,  you can attach preventDefault() to prohibit the page from continuing. There you can launch your modal and upon completing whatever you need to do in the modal you can change the `window.location` object to forward the page to the intended target.

Comment: unfortunately I'm still struggling with this, I have tried a couple of combinations of functions, methods and modal dialogs following your advice, none are working exactly as I would want them to work.

Your information is great and on spot, however it seems the final solution is elusive to me for whatever reason.

I will keep trying.
Thanks :)

Comment: after searching and trying extensively, it really seems that it's impossible (at least at the present day) to prevent alert and confirmation dialogs from appearing BEFORE stylized dialog box.

This is what I have at the moment
http://passiveprofitsfactory.com/working-exit-popup.html
1. In IE and FF, first alert box appears with the text and OK button. Then confirmation dialog as well.
2. In Chrome, there's no alert, but the confirmation together with the text appears.

I'd need something prettier than these ugly dialogs, however so far I'm unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar requirements where I wanted to use nice HTML message instead of default js message. After spending some time I finally found a way to do it. I have used jQuery [Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) modal which is very useful in any modal requirement, not just here.

Basically you can use `mousemove` event and find if Y coordinate (`e.clientY` ) is less than 5. So it will be fired every time when mouse is near address bar (user typing new URL or trying to close window).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    if (e.clientY <= 5) {
        jQuery.colorbox({initialHeight: 250, initialWidth: 250, html:'<h2>any custom HTML here</h2><br/><img src="nice-img" />'});
    }
});
```

});

I found many example using `e.pageY` but note that it will only be fired if user has not scrolled down. So if you scroll down even for 5 pixel, `e.pageY` will not work, but `e.clientY` will work. 
`e.pageY` gives offset while `e.clientY` gives absolute coordinate. Very important!