# disable chrome pop-up window " leave site? changes you made may not be savecd" after submit form

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple form where the user chooses a value that I will be saved in the database.
**HTML**

```
<form  method="get" >
        <div class="select-block1">
            <select name="proximID" onchange="this.form.submit(); ">
                <option value="" disabled selected> Votre Proxim'IT</option>
                <?php foreach ($results as $output){?>

                <option value="<?php echo $output['id']; ?>"> <?php echo $output["first_name"], $output["last_name"]; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
         
        </div>
    </form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 
if(!empty($_GET['proximID'])) { 

$stmt6 = $pdo1->query("UPDATE proximit SET ProximID = {$_GET['proximID']} "); ?>
```

when i choose a value, pop-up window appear " leave site?" changes you made may not be savecd". Please how can i disable this pop-up window for chrome

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent "Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?" alert on form submission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183682/how-to-prevent-are-you-sure-you-want-to-navigate-away-from-this-page-alert-on)

Comment: So where is your onbeforeunload code?

Comment: @epascarello I forgot to mention that I already did some research before asking my question. and actually I used onbeforeunload like the solution suggested below and it didn't work. I will be very grateful if you can suggest me a solution.

Comment: Does your code have onbeforeunload  set anywhere? Browser does not do it by default.

Comment: @epascarello actually i am working on the open source Osticket so i don't know if there is onbeforeunload set anywhere

Comment: I think that uses jQuery? So try `$(window).unbind('beforeunload');`

Comment: Indeed they use JQuery 3.4.0.  And still not working :/

Answer (score 0):

That popup is shown because the `onsubmit` event triggers a page refresh which also calls `onbeforeunload` event.

From the docs:
The [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) event is fired when the window, the document and its resources are about to be unloaded. The document is still visible and the event is still cancelable at this point.

To take control over this popup, you need to modify this event.

Add an `id` attribute to the `<form>` tag

```
<form  method="get" id="selectForm" >
```

Assign `onChange` a function

```
<select name="proximID" onchange="onSelectHandler();">
```

which triggers

```
function onSelectHandler() {
    const form = document.getElementById('selectForm');
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
    form.submit();
}
```

Comment: thank you soo much for your answer, but i didn't work for me :/

Comment: which chrome version are you on? did you try on mozilla?

Comment: the version of chrome is 100.0.4896.127. We don't work with mozilla. I have the same probleme with Microsoft Edge