# exit confirmation message javascript

Tags: php, return, message, exit, confirm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to show the “Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?” when changes committed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119289/how-to-show-the-are-you-sure-you-want-to-navigate-away-from-this-page-when-ch)

I use a javascript message for confirming people who will exit the page, just if the for is not save, so I have the following code:

```
  <body onLoad="getdate2()" <?php if(!isset($_POST['enreg'])){ echo 
'onBeforeUnload="return(\'Vous n avez pas enregistr&eacute; les modifications 
apport&eacute;es. voulez vous vraiment quitter la page ?\')' ; } ?>">
```

The main trouble is that when The user click on the form submit button, this message appears.

Is there a way to just display that when the user click on the cross for exiting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're expecting PHP to affect how a page works in the browser. It doesn't work like that.

You need to remove the PHP and just leave the `onBeforeUnload` event. Then, in the `onClick` event of the Submit button, remove the `onBeforeUnload` event.