# "Are you sure you want to leave this page?" functions for cancel and OK

Tags: onbeforeunload, dismiss

i'm trying to do something similar to some websites where you leave and it'll display a popup saying "Are you sure you want to leave this page" and with two options saying "Cancel" and "OK".

How would I do that and make it so when you click "Cancel" it'll just cancel the box and when they click "OK" it'll do a 'leaveChat();' function and leave the website?

I've tried using the onbeforeunload which was working but i'm not sure on the function part.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show the "Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?" when changes committed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119289/how-to-show-the-are-you-sure-you-want-to-navigate-away-from-this-page-when-ch)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that.

You can try sending the AJAX request in `onunload`, but I don't think that will work reliably.

Comment: I've seen it on quite a few websites though?:/

Comment: @user1783703: You've seen _what_? `onbeforeunload` does not tell you what the user clicked.

Answer (score 0):

To pop a message when the user is leaving the page to confirm leaving, you just do:

```
<script>
    window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
      return 'Are you sure you want to leave this page?  You will lose any unsaved data.';
    };
</script>
```

To call a function:

```
<script>
    window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
       callSomeFunction();
       return null;
    };
</script>
```

Comment: The browser will handle the user's click and decide to leave the page or stay on.  No browser that I know of gives you the control to keep the user on the page and not let them leave.

Answer (score 0):

here is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE HMTL>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

 <body onload="myFunction()">
    <h1 id="belong">
        Welcome To My Home
    </h1>
    <p>
        <a id="replaceME" onclick="myFunction2(event)" href="https://www.ccis.edu">I am a student at Columbia College of Missouri.</a>
    </p>
</body>
```

And so this is how I did something similar in javaScript

```
var myGlobalNameHolder ="";

function myFunction(){
var myString = prompt("Enter a name", "Name Goes Here");
    myGlobalNameHolder = myString;
    if (myString != null) {
        document.getElementById("replaceME").innerHTML =
        "Hello " + myString + ". Welcome to my site";

        document.getElementById("belong").innerHTML =
        "A place you belong";
    }   
}

// create a function to pass our event too
function myFunction2(event) {   
// variable to make our event short and sweet
var x=window.onbeforeunload;
// logic to make the confirm and alert boxes
if (confirm("Are you sure you want to leave my page?") == true) {
    x = alert("Thank you " + myGlobalNameHolder + " for visiting!");
}
}
```