# How to change the text of “Are you sure you want to leave this page?” function script of "onunload"?

Tags: javascript, popup, translate, onunload

How to change the text of this function script?:

> window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
>         return 'Are you sure you want to leave this page?  You will lose any unsaved data.';
>       };

i want to translate the text " 'Are you sure you want to leave this page?  You will lose any unsaved data.' " so it can say the same but in my language... 
how to do it?
Please help - thanks

(when i translate it, it doesnt change in the frontend).
Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: i saw the script from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843454/are-you-sure-you-want-to-leave-this-page-functions-for-cancel-and-ok

Comment: The browser should display that in the user's default language, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately, changing the message seems to only work in Internet Explorer (see [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onbeforeunload.asp)). I don't think you'll be able to insert blocking code either(such as `alert()`), as it would be a security breach for the browser).

Comment: thanks, this helps me at least to stop bumping my head around it :).

Comment: can you check my other question below please? u seem to know the stuff better than me :) - thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

also how to make the function be "on" for all external pages and be disabled for any inside pages like "domain.com -> domain.com/about-us" 
?

Comment: for links, you could add an onclick="checkExternal(event)". the function checkExternal can then check the pointed url, and act accordingly. for example by calling event.preventDefault() and only redirecting after an `if(confirm("you sure?"))`

Comment: that's a question in and of itself (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22382151/confirm-leave-on-external-links-in-wordpress for example).

Comment: so just to be clear - i have to type this:
<script> 
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) { return 'Are you sure you want to leave this page? You will lose any unsaved data.'; };
onclick="checkExternal(event)"
</script>


or i have to do something else?
i know its probably a dumb question but its just a bit over my ability ... :(.
thanks in advance for your kind help

Comment: no, not at all. you don't need `onbeforeunload` at all, an every `<a>` on your page needs an onclick event please refer to this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/22382322/161622. it has all you want

Comment: i saw it and i wrote there , but hmm i am not so good in java and there is a loot of code(not only java) there...
so i couldnt figure out how to implement it exactly :(.
its really confusing  - may be you can give me a pointer or 2 as you give to all the other novices you meet ?
Thanks really much in advance for your help. I trully can say that if someone doesnt help me i probably wont figure it out. I spent like a day and a half to try figure it out already and i had verry little progress.
:(

Comment: ok that's going to be longer than a comment. You should really ask a new question, so that we can answer it properly. and maybe link it here so I find it :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41814038/how-to-make-the-onbeforeunload-function-be-disabled-for-my-own-pages-and-work
here is the link- thanks in advance really :)