# Jquery event doesn't fire in any case

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, here I want just to alert true, when window is closed ( I mean particullary tab in browser).

```
$(document).ready(function(){



});
$(window).unload(function(){
    alert('true'); });
```

tried `$(window)` also inside `$(document).ready()`, nothing.

Comment: what browser are you using?  I think Chrome may prevent stuff like this from happening (because it's annoying)

Comment: Firefox, but actually I don't want to attack user with alert, just delete cookie, here I'm just testing

Comment: you might try `onbeforeunload`...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119289/how-to-show-the-are-you-sure-you-want-to-navigate-away-from-this-page-when-ch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're very limited in what you can do in the context of `window.unload`.  The browsers won't let you do anything to force the user to stay on the page, and that includes calling `alert`.

The best thing you're allowed to do is return a string from an `onbeforeunload` handler - the browser will display that to the user, along with a question like "Are you sure you want to leave this page?"

Comment: @JoeHalfFace doesn't matter. It's only code used to bind the callback. It's not executed until the event is fired.

Comment: thanks, I will accept when SoF lets me, it is so stupid, I wanted to delete cookie, but to test if event works decided to try it with alert, and spent nearly hour trying out to figure out why there is no alert