# Jquery a href onclick to controller without reload page

Tags: javascript, jquery, reload

I am trying to write a code that includes confirm message by using jquery.

İf ı click to Exit according to my below code occurs reload of my page.

```
<a href="Exit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to exit?')">Exit</a>
```

How can ı write above code without reload page with confirm message in Jquery ?

İf confirm ok = go to href (without reload)
İf confirm cancel = cancel it,

Comment: That has nothing to do with jQuery. Apart from that, your code should just work. It will only reload if you hit 'ok'.

Comment: @putvande Since he's asking how to do it using jQuery, please don't remove the jQuery tag.  He's not saying the above code doesn't work.  He's asked for an alternative.

Comment: Fair enough. The the question was unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try the following code**

```
<a href="#Exit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to exit?'); return false">Exit</a>
```

**Explanation:**

`#` A URL fragment is a name preceded by a hash mark (#), which specifies an internal target location (an ID) within the current document.

While `return false` is a way to tell the event to not actually fire.

[**See Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6AY3F/)

Answer (score 1):

I use this function to do something like that :

```
function confirm_text_url(message, url){
    var response = confirm(message);
    if (response==true)
    {
        document.location.href=url;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code will obviously already work, but since you've asked for it this is the same thing, but using jQuery to assign the event handler...

**HTML**

```
<a href="Exit" id="exit-link">Exit</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
    $("#exit-link").on("click", function() {
        return confirm("Are you sure you want to exit?");
    });
});
```

I added an ID to the link, just to be able to explicitly reference it using jQuery.  Other than that it's the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

from the text in your confirm I guess you might be looking for this:
[How to show the "Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?" when changes committed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119289/how-to-show-the-are-you-sure-you-want-to-navigate-away-from-this-page-when-ch)

or dicussed in more detail regarding support for older browsers:
[How to show the "Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?" when changes committed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119289/how-to-show-the-are-you-sure-you-want-to-navigate-away-from-this-page-when-ch)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to evaluate the result

ex:

```
var r=confirm("Are you sure you want to exit?");
if (r==true)
  {
  x="You pressed OK!";
  }
else
  {
  x="You pressed Cancel!";
  }
```

in your case, it would be something like:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="confirm('Are you sure you want to exit?') ? window.location = 'page-to-go-to': return ">Exit</a>
```

Also, use javascript:void(0); as the href, so you're sure the default propagation is not triggered