# Stop page from refreshing in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

This stopLeave func. is assigned to 'onbeforeunload' event. What do i do to stop page from refreshing or closing explorer when user press cancel??

### Javascript

```
    function stopLeave(){
    var a = confirm('are you sure you want to leave? you have unsaved work');
    if (a){
         what do i write here? } else
      {   what do i write here?
           }
     }
```

Comment: You should definetely show more code here...

Comment: You can never hinder the user to leave the page, you can only remind him that it might be not wise.

Comment: i have no idea what code should be written in if..else block.. i've searched but no clear response..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show the "Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?" when changes committed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119289/how-to-show-the-are-you-sure-you-want-to-navigate-away-from-this-page-when-ch)

Comment: @bergi what shud I do when user does not wants to leave. how do i stop browser to not complete the action..

Comment: return confirm('are you sure you want to leave? you have unsaved work');

Comment: @kamlesh when I refresh the page it shows the confirm box.. but when i press cancel it again refreshes the page.. how do i stop browser to cancel the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if you do it with vanila javascript and need to ensure cross-browser compatibility:

```
function stopLeave(e){
    var message = 'Are you sure you want to leave?'; 
    var e = e || window.event;
    if (e) {
        e.returnValue = message ;
    }
    return message;
}
```

Comment: `<body onbeforeunload="stopLeave(what goes in here?)">`

Comment: @Parminder: if you bind event handler this way, try `<body onbeforeunload="stopLeave(event)">`

Comment: @Parminder: another way is `window.onbeforeunload = stopLeave`

Answer (score 0):

Just return the question string:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Are you sure you want to leave? you have unsaved work";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent a user from closing a page. All you can do is allow the *browser* to ask the user if he wants to leave, like this:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() { return 'are you sure you want to leave? you have unsaved work'; });
```