# What is the default behavior for onbeforeunload in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

In IE, if the window.onbeforeunload function returns a null, it will still pop up an alert window. How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Don't return anything at all.  Presumably, `return;` or `return undefined;` would work, but I usually just have it end the function without a `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

If it's anything (including a function that returns null) IE will still show the dialog.

In IE you have to clear the function entirely.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119289/how-to-show-the-are-you-sure-you-want-to-navigate-away-from-this-page-when-ch/1119324#1119324) for more detail.