# JqueryMobile (SPA) Disable Browser backbutton and Refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

hi i am using jqueryMobile SPA template for  my phone-gap app.

For web version my requirement is to disable or show warning message to user on click of browser back button. I googled my requirement but didn't find any desired solution.Please guide me . Thanks.

Comment: maybe this post has info you can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119289/how-to-show-the-are-you-sure-you-want-to-navigate-away-from-this-page-when-ch

Comment: It's not possible to disable it, in fact, you shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable Backbutton of browser i used

```
 $(window).on("navigate", function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     window.history.forward(1);

});
```

But on pressing f5 it was creating error and redirecting me to login page.Thus i disable   f5 ,ctrl+R button.

```
 var ctrlKeyDown = false;
 $(document).on("pagecreate", function (){    
    $(document).on("keydown", keydown);
    $(document).on("keyup", keyup);
 });

 function keydown(e) { 
   if ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 116 || ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 82 && ctrlKeyDown))
    {
     // Pressing F5 or Ctrl+R
     e.preventDefault();
    } else if ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 17) {
    // Pressing  only Ctrl
    ctrlKeyDown = true;
  }
}

function keyup(e){
  // Key up Ctrl
 if ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 17) 
    ctrlKeyDown = false;
}
```

It completely fulfilled my requirement.Thanks to Suhas :) .

Comment: You may need to push an initial state to make this work...  Something like this
      `window.onload = function() {
        if (window.history && history.pushState) {
          history.pushState(null, null, null);
        }
      };`

Answer (score 1):

Try this- 
[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xKJB8/760/)

```
$(window).on("navigate", function (event, data) {
    var direction = data.state.direction;
    if ( !! direction) {
        alert(direction);
    }
});
```

Please refer following link.

[**Refer This**](http://www.irt.org/script/311.htm)

Or you can use

```
window.history.forward(1);
```

when back button get pressed. But it loads and then redirected not proper way.

Comment: thanks. this is working fine but is it possible to disable back button

Comment: @varun you can show warning message as per your requirement.

Comment: that is ok,but it does not stop page navigation.I want to stop navigation with warning message

Comment: @varun I have edited my answer please find that link.

Comment: thanks Suhas,i used your code to fulfill my requirement.I will post the code i used.