# How to disable "Authentication Required" and "Confirm Navigation" Popup

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

A project I am working on all of a sudden start showing "Authentication Required" and "Confirm Navigation" Popup when some `links` are clicked. I am using `angularjs` on .net `MVC` project. How do I disable this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think one of your MVC Controller has [Authorization] attribute, please remove it it will fix the problem.

Comment: A missing [Authorization] attribute fixed the "Authentication Required"

Comment: This worked only on my local but still happen on the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

For Authentication how its configured in IIS? If not anonymous user it will show like this

For navigation pop up go through [How to show the "Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?" when changes committed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119289/how-to-show-the-are-you-sure-you-want-to-navigate-away-from-this-page-when-ch)