# user should get an alert before navigating if he has not submitted otherwise navigate to the desired location

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am trying to develop a webpage where the user is giving online test and if he has not submitted that test and then try to navigate to another page, he should get a confirmation message that his answers will not be saved if he leaves his test. How shall i go?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show the "Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?" when changes committed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119289/how-to-show-the-are-you-sure-you-want-to-navigate-away-from-this-page-when-ch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onbeforeunload` event:

```
var submitted = false;
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
   if (!submitted) {
       return "Are you sure you want to leave this page, your test will not be saved?";
   }
};
document.getElementById('someForm').onsubmit = function() {
    submitted = true;
    // submit the form using ajax
};
```

Comment: this is working but not navgating to other page if clicked yes

Answer (score 0):

Create a function which validates the form. When the user click on 'a' tag (trying to navigate), call that function and alert him if he not submitted the test.

Comment: i am doing this actually-this is my script
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function abc() {
           confirm("do u want 2 cont.");
       }

        
</script>
this is where i am calling that script-
 <div id="page-wrapper" onmouseleave="abc();">
it works fine on mouseleave but i want it to work only when the user has not submitted

Comment: @Ramesh, can you post some code to demonstrate what you mean? Thanks