# IE 8 shows constantly alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, alert

In a ASP MVC Project we have a site with a search form. this works quite well in IE 9, 10...

but in IE 8 we get constantly this warning

> Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?
>
> Message from website: true

The site has a form  which is mainly the input for some search data.
The form is realtiv big i just show some elements below

```
<form method="get" action="/search/" novalidate="novalidate">
```

There are now 4 some inputs and a submit button.

Are there any known case in which IE 8 shows this kind of alerts where 9 and 10 don't ?

As Frameworks which may be related we have primarly knockout and jquery in this site.

Comment: Do you have a custom `window.onbeforeunload` event? You could try adding `window.onbeforeunload = null;` in your script. If you search the message, there are plenty of posts on it. Here's one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119289/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was not a the form it self. We added a shim which caused this behavior. removed it and it works