# Execute Javascript on Refresh Without the "Are you sure you want to leave the page" Prompt

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a certain case, I need to execute a few lines when the user refreshes the page.

Currently I do this with the `onbeforeunload` event as shown below, **but I am looking for a way to do this without the prompt. I just want it to  happen behind the scenes**

The solution can be pure JS (preferred) or could be jQuery based.

```
//to kill the modal incase refresh or page exit
window.onbeforeunload = closingCode;
function closingCode() {

    //bunch of functions here to run before refresh/close


    window.location.href = window.location.href.split('#')[0]; //remove leftover hash symbol if it exists
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Remove it..What is the concern ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1119324/709439

Comment: Which prompt do you mean? Is there some relevant code in `inst` we're missing? Looks like it works: https://jsfiddle.net/h6sp16r9/

Comment: just remove `false` only `return;`

Comment: Yeah the inst. stuff is just a bunch of functions I needed to run before closing/refreshing... commented them out as they aren't relevant to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ;)

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  inst.close();
  inst.destroy();
  window.location.href = window.location.href.split('#')[0]; //remove leftover hash symbol if it exists
  return;
}
```

Comment: Yup, simply using `return;` without `null` or `false` did the trick.