# Confirm box on browser back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, back-button

I want to catch the event on back or refresh button of browser. I didn't found any perfect solution that catches only back event and which is compatible with all browsers. please provide some solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: forgot to mention that i am working on java

Comment: javascript . What ever may be just want to catch that event

Comment: Do you want to do something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119289/how-to-show-the-are-you-sure-you-want-to-navigate-away-from-this-page-when-ch

Comment: well i have used onbeforeunload function before. I want web page to provide a confirm box only when back/refresh button of browser  is pressed. onbeforeunload  triggered every time before leaving that page. so I was not able to navigate to other other pages. if i navigate to other jsp it was showing the confirm box which i don't want. I want something that can capture an event of back/refresh button only. that's what exactly i want..

Comment: Did you try to turn it off once is triggered? window.onbeforeunload = null;

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo , I tried that solution. that kind of worked. now it is not triggered on submission of form but only on back.

Comment: window.onbeforeunload = function() { return "Your work will be lost." }.. Now i m using this. but the problem now is that now i want a confirm box and if user clicks ok then i want to redirect to a url in controller. i.e i want to invalidate the session . but onbeforeload by default gives confirmation box and if i press ok it will go back to previous page which i dont want. Can you help me with this confirm box thing??

Comment: onbeforeload only returns null or string and we also cannot use confirm inside that...please provide some solution for that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.userInteractionTimeout = null;
window.userInteractionInHTMLArea = false;
window.onBrowserHistoryButtonClicked = null; // This will be your event handler for browser navigation buttons clicked

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).mousedown(function() {
        clearTimeout(window.userInteractionTimeout);
        window.userInteractionInHTMLArea = true;
        window.userInteractionTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
            window.userInteractionInHTMLArea = false;
        }, 500);
    });

    $(document).keydown(function() {
        clearTimeout(window.userInteractionTimeout);
        window.userInteractionInHTMLArea = true;
        window.userInteractionTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
            window.userInteractionInHTMLArea = false;
        }, 500);
    });

    if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
        $(window).on('popstate', function() {
            if (!window.userInteractionInHTMLArea) {
                //document.location.href = "logOff.htm";
                setTimeout(function(){  var answer = confirm("Are you Sure?? This will expire your session");
                if(answer == true)
                    {
                    document.location.href = "logOff.htm";  
                    }
                },100 );


                //alert('Browser Back or Forward button was pressed.');
            }
            if (window.onBrowserHistoryButtonClicked) {

                window.onBrowserHistoryButtonClicked();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Found another solution. Than you  all of you for your support.

Comment: Hello can you please share your solution over here

Comment: @siddharthshah above snippet worked for me at that time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event handler `onpopstate` from HTML5 history API, like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {

$(window).on('popstate', function() {
  //confirmation box
  confirm('Back button clicked!');
});
 }
});
```

Note that you need to have a page to go back to...