# Is it possible to use Tapestry PageLink and onBeforeOnLoad together?

Tags: tapestry, onbeforeunload

I'm looking to check the page for changes and alerting the user before they leave if items have not been saved.  Is it possible to use onBeforeOnLoad with a PageLink from Tapestry?  I've tried and so far have had no luck.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meant `onbeforeunload`, which is javascript and wouldn't have anything do with your page link. Instead, add a script tag at the end of your page with the snippet below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return true;
};
</script>
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1119324/473637) answer for more info.