# Detecte and delete data if user click go back button in the broswer

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, asp.net

I am working an application where each time the user open the page atomatically genrate an id for that page using the database. 
 All data is stored with that id when the user click save button (the saving button in a server side ) . But how I can do that, If the user click the go back or close buttons in the brower I want a window appear with some text like "You forget to click save button to save your work , If you leave you will lose your work!". In the same time I want to delete the id if the user did not click save button and leave the page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show the "Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?" when changes committed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119289/how-to-show-the-are-you-sure-you-want-to-navigate-away-from-this-page-when-ch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

            if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {

                window.history.pushState('forward', null, './#forward');

                $(window).on('popstate', function () {
                    alert('hey wait You Clicked Back Button');
                    //your Code here

                });

            }
        });
     </script>
```

Comment: For backward compatibility you can also go through: history.js

Comment: Where I should put it ? I tried to put it in the end of the html body and no action!

Comment: you have to add  between <head> <script>  here   </script>

Comment: I added it like that still no action!             <head runat="server">
    <title>EmptyWeb</title>
     <script>

   
      jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

          if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {

              window.history.pushState('forward', null, './#forward');

              $(window).on('popstate', function () {
                  alert('hey wait You Clicked Back Button');
                  //your Code here

              });

          }
      });

  </script>

Comment: Thank you for your answer but still doesn't work with me !

Comment: TRY to run on different browser because its working in my Internet explorer 11

Comment: where are u clicking for back??

Comment: I was using chrome now i switch to IE . It give me this exeption :             0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'jQuery' is undefined

Comment: check latest answer and copy it and let me know if it wont work you were missing j query class that's why it was not working and if it will work then mark it as an answer

Comment: now it shows the window when i click go back in the browser but the data still in the database.

Comment: you have to fire your submit button where i have written ** your code here**

Comment: its Detecting user click go back button in the broswer  now you have to use it as you want to use it