# How do you prompt a user before they leave a webpage with a custom message?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use `window.confirm` because you can set a custom message whereas with `window.onbeforeunload`, [you cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276660/how-can-i-override-the-onbeforeunload-dialog-and-replace-it-with-my-own?answertab=active#tab-top).

Something like `window.onbeforeunload = () => window.confirm('Are you sure you want to leave')` would be nice, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You cannot. It is a security risk. Please see [this awesome explainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119289/how-to-show-the-are-you-sure-you-want-to-navigate-away-from-this-page-when-ch)

Comment: @stever Gonna assume you meant to link the first answer. Thought it'd be more in depth, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this. I think this is what you asked for

```
window.onbeforeunload = popup;

function popup() {
  return 'I see you are leaving the site';
}
```

Comment: This used to work, but virtually all browsers removed support for custom `unbeforeunload` text around 2017.