# Use Prompt from React Router to block history.push

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using React-Router's Prompt component to block a user from switching tabs when a form is in a dirty state. Each tab has its own route and I'm using `history.push` to update the URL. `Prompt` shows up as expected when the form is dirty, but the user is still taken to the new URL when they click "cancel".

Here is the function that handles switching tabs and updating the URL.

```js
const handleClick = (tabId, disabled, route) => {
    if (disabled) {
        return false;
    }
    setSelectedIndex(tabId);
    if (route) {
        history.push(route);
    }
    return true;
};
```

I'm guessing that `history.push` gets executed not matter what.

Every example I see of using `Prompt` shows it being used with `Link`. Is there a way to get `Prompt` to work with `history.push`?

Comment: The answer in this question looks like it does what you want. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119289/how-to-show-the-are-you-sure-you-want-to-navigate-away-from-this-page-when-ch

Comment: I've seen that one before. Unfortunately pushing to the history stack does not fire the browser's unload event.

Comment: this is the code for prompt https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/modules/Prompt.js#L19 maybe history.block might work? haven't tried it myself

Comment: My understanding is that `history.block` is going away https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/issues/690

Comment: @MichaelTurnwall I am trying to accomplish the same thing, did you ever solve this?

Comment: Yes, you can use https://michaelchan-13570.medium.com/using-react-router-v4-prompt-with-custom-modal-component-ca839f5faf39 . It blocks history.push and history.replace (I'd add it as an answer, but since I'm not the original author of the solution, I preferred to let it here)