Angular - @HostListener - Completely prevent page refresh
I'm using @HostListener to prevent the window reload. I have implemented my code like following -
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
unloadNotification($event: any) {
  let checkSave = true;
  for( let index = 0; index < this.data.length; index++ ) {
    if( !this.data[index].id ) {
      checkSave = false;
      break;
    }
  }

  if( !checkSave ) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(SomeComponent, {
      data: { 
        refresh: true
      }, width: '500px'
    });
 
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      if( result.refresh ) {
        this.data = [];
        window.location.reload();
      }
    } );

    $event.preventDefault();
  }
}

I'm trying to restrict refresh if any object in my data array is missing id. In that case, I show an Angular material dialog asking for confirmation. The above code works absolutely fine, the only issue is that when I refresh my page, a confirm window pops up asking for confirmation to reload and then my Angular material dialog is shown. I don't want that confirm window to show as I have already handled the page refresh using Angular dialog.
Question - Is there any way to either completely prevent page refresh or programmatically click on the 'Cancel' button when the confirm window pops up?
Update -
Attaching screenshots of what happens. When I click on refresh, the browser specific confirmation window appears -

Then after I click on cancel, the below pops up as per my code -


This is not angular specific.
Modern browsers does not allow to popup custom dialog when closing browser or navigating away from your html page.
However, you can still display generic message box:
// Enable navigation prompt
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return true;
};


See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1119324/475727

For security reason there are no possibility to totally prevent a page refresh.

Browsers don't allow web pages to cancel unloading of the page, because it can be misused. The only thing you can do is to open a browser-generated confirmation dialog that asks the user to confirm if they really want to leave the page. However, it's not possible to open a custom dialog. To trigger this dialog, set the beforeunload event's returnValue to a truthy value:
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
unloadNotification($event: Event) {
  let checkSave = true;
  for( let index = 0; index < this.data.length; index++ ) {
    if( !this.data[index].id ) {
      checkSave = false;
      break;
    }
  }

  if( !checkSave ) {
    $event.returnValue = true;
  }
}

Depending on the browser and operating system, it can look somewhat like the following:

For more information, check the docs.

Thanks for pointing this. But I'm able to open a customized dialog on page refresh. As you can see in my code, when I refresh my page, a browser specific confirm window pops up first. When I click cancel or reload then my customized dialog is shown. I was hoping if we could programmatically click on cancel when the browser specific dialog appears.
