# Prompt user for unsaved changes when leaving webpage

Tags: javascript, firefox

What options do I have preventing the user from just closing the browser or navigating to another site? (of course I can't prevent him pulling the plug on the computer, etc.: I just want to show him a warning)

Comment: Duplicate - the exact same question was asked nine minutes before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299452/how-do-i-stop-a-page-from-unloading-navigating-away-in-js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the JS `beforeunload` event in order to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the onunload event.

```
<script>
function onExitHandler() {
  // called when user about to leave the page
}
</script>
<body onunload="onExitHandler()">
...
</body>
```

You can see an example here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_onunload.asp

Comment: The unload event is too late. You have to use beforeunload if you want to prevent the user leaving (which was the question).