# How do I stop a page from unloading with standardized JavaScript (Not `onbeforeunload`)

Tags: javascript, html, events, onunload

*Before you relink me, I've read questions like [How do I stop a page from unloading (navigating away) in JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299452/how-do-i-stop-a-page-from-unloading-navigating-away-in-js), but they deal with HTML4 and below. I want an answer that utilizes the HTML5 event attribute `onunload`. I also want this to be as pure as possible, that is without external libraries or plugins like jQuery or Flash and only using standardized code (**PURE** HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, nothing platform-dependant).*

**Before you tell me to use `onbeforeunload`, note that it is *NON-STANDARD*, and therefore does not fit my criteria as described above. It does NOT work on all browsers, especially those made before IE implemented it.**

### Question

---

On my site, I have several music players, and if any one of them is playing when the user attempts to navigate away from the page, I want to popup a dialog box ensuring that they intended this and that they understand that this will stop the audio stream, and if they choose "yes" or "OK", it proceeds with the navigation, but if they click "no" or "Cancel", it stays on the same page and keeps playing the audio without a break. **How do I use JavaScript to cancel the page unloading WITHOUT USING `ONBEFOREUNLOAD`?**

### Code so far

---

I have the following code so far, but no idea how to stop unloading:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>
<head>
    <script><!-- Loading Scripts -->
    function unloadTasks(){
        window.alert(":" + playing + ":");
        if (playing && !window.confirm("A podcast is playing, and navigating away from this page will stop that. Are you sure you want to go?"))
            window.alert("Here is where I will stop the page from unloading... somehow");
    }
    </script>
    <script><!-- Player Scripts -->
    var playing = false;
    function logPlay(){
        playing = isPlaying("e1audPlayer");
    }
    function isPlaying(player){
        return document.getElementById(player).currentTime > 0 && !document.getElementById(player).paused && !document.getElementById(player).ended;
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onunload="unloadTasks()">
<audio id="e1audPlayer" style="width:100%;" controls="controls" preload="auto" onplaying="logPlay()" onpause="logPlay()">
    <source src="http://s.supuhstar.operaunite.com/s/content/pod/ADHD Episode 001.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
    <source src="http://s.supuhstar.operaunite.com/s/content/pod/ADHD Episode 001.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
    Your browser does not support embedded audio players. Try <a href="http://opera.com/">Opera</a> or <a href="http://chrome.com/">Chrome</a>
</audio>
<a href="http://example.com/">Link away</a>
</body>
</html>
```

[Working example](http://s.supuhstar.operaunite.com/s/content/pod/playerTest.htm)

Comment: You need `onbeforeunload`, *not* `onunload`.  `onunload` fires after the browser has already committed to unloading the page, and cannot request a cancel.

Comment: see my edit on `onbeforeunload`

Comment: If you can't use `onbeforeunload`, I do not believe there is any way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not prevent this entirely, however can notify the user via a popup that he should not reload. This is done with the onbeforeunload window event, best documented at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload).

This will behave exactly like here on Stackoverflow, if you add some text to the answer textarea and than try to leave the page.

Comment: Than there is no way to solve your problem. Please remember: You are using the web, a incredible, dynamic and free medium, that is also splintered, broken and horrible sometimes. Try to rethink your reasoning, there is always a multitude of possibilities to accomplish usability.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using onbeforeunload to prompt the user with the message.

Comment: Using alert in onbeforeunload actually not works reliable. One of the last Mozilla browsers disabled this.

Comment: @FloydThreepwood No where do I mention an alert. There should be no reason for an alert with unbeforeunload, the message should be in the onbeforeunload prompt.

Comment: @epascarello No Link and no code, I just assumed this. 'Prompt'ing something also has a multitude of meanings. Sorry, got it the other way round.

Comment: @Supuhstar it is impossible without this event. You can not stop the unload, it is too late at the point you are trying to block it. You can not make web applications act like client applications. You are stuck with what the environment you are in and can use only the tools they give you.

Comment: @epascarello I know... that's why I'm asking if there are any tools they gave me which will stop unloading.

Comment: @Supuhstar yes, that even is onbeforeunload ;)

Comment: `onbeforeunload` is not given to me, by your definition above, as my environment is the standard one.