# How do some websites prevent you from leaving?

Tags: javascript, html, web, spam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you prevent javascript page from navigating away?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821011/how-do-you-prevent-javascript-page-from-navigating-away)
>   [How do I stop a page from unloading (navigating away) in JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299452/how-do-i-stop-a-page-from-unloading-navigating-away-in-js)

I have been on several websites, sorry I cant provide the url, that do not let you leave. No matter what you do, besides force quitting (closing the page, navigating to a new url, regular quitting, you cant leave). These websites always have an alert box that asks you a question like: "do you want to leave?" but both answers (yes and cancel) leave you back on their page. I would just like to know how they do this.
**will not use this in my website, I am not a spammer just wondering**

Answer (score 4):

With this code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    return 'Are you sure you wanna leave my website?';//Displays an confirm box and, if you click cancel, you will stay on the page. Otherwise, you'll leave the page
}
```

However, putting this code on your website will make your viewers very angry. Therefore I warn you against it