# How can I confirm page changes while using history.js?

Tags: javascript, ajax, dialog, browser-history, history.js

I am using history.js and ajaxify.js to make my web app ajax enabled.  If the user has unsaved changes on the form and they try to go to another page, I need to show them a warning that they will lose their changes if they leave.

I would normally just use `window.onbeforeunload = unloadPage;` but this doesn't fire with ajax page loads.  How can I prevent the page from changing if they don't want to lose their unsaved edits?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299452/how-do-i-stop-a-page-from-unloading-navigating-away-in-js

Comment: Not a duplicate.  That question has nothing to do with ajax page loads, and as I stated, `onbeforeunload` would not work.

Comment: Well don't you just answer at your own question by saying that it's an ajax request that is done? I mean you only need to check this before each ajax call. Just create a custom function that will call your ajax function and accepts the same parameters and use it.