# Unable to unbind onbeforeunload in IE

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload, unbind

I am using OAF framework which automatically binds a function to onbeforeunload event(like `onbeforeunload="_savePageStateIE()"`).

I am using the below code unbind standard func and bind a custom func. But it is working in all browsers except IE.

```
<html>
<script>
window.onbeforeunload=null;
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;

function confirmExit()
{
return "You have attempted to leave this page.";
}
</script>
<body onbeforeunload="_savePageStateIE()">
<h1 style="color:red">Hello World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it should be `confirm` instead of return

Comment: your script block should be at the end of the page just before `</body>`

Comment: @Justcode your code is also working in chrome not in IE. I need it in IE

Comment: @ArupNayak you should describe it in your question

Comment: @Justcode its not working as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
  <!-- put html code here -->
</body>

function myFunction() {
   var redirect = confirm("Redirect to url ?");
   if (redirect == true) {
       window.location.href = 'url'; //redirect to url.
   }
}
```

Or should be like this

```
var warning = true;
window.onbeforeunload = function() { 
  if (warning) {
    return "You have made changes on this page that you have not yet confirmed. If you navigate away from this page you will lose your unsaved changes";
  }
}

$('form').submit(function() {
   window.onbeforeunload = null;
});
```

I found upper one from here :- [Url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3929024/2630817)

Especially for ie..

```
<script>
    $(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
        return "This should create a pop-up";
    });
</script>
```