# Closing a tab using ascii codes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ascii

Ive read earlier that we cannot close the current tab using jQuery or Javascript.

My question is, Is it possible to use the ASCII codes for "ctrl+w" (that is 23) and calling it in jquery/JS to close the current tab?

I tried this code:

```
<script>
function closethis(){
    $(document).keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 23) {
            alert('Are you sure you want to close?');
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

but doesnt work.. any leads??

Comment: You're trying to send a command (shortcut) to the browser. This is not possible. Otherwise, you would be able to do other things like even close the browser itself (Alt + F4), which obviously doesn't make much sense.

Comment: yeah i know.. was just trying an alternative to close the current tab.. but none are working. I cannot use window.close() in my case as i am not opening a new window using JS..so that.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot close windows your script hasn't opened in any way.

(If your script opened a window with `var newWindow = window.open(...)`, you can close it with `newWindow.close()`.)

The most you can do in windows that you didn't open is show a dialog box *when the tab is being closed by the user*. For that, see [How do I stop a page from unloading (navigating away) in JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299452/how-do-i-stop-a-page-from-unloading-navigating-away-in-js) and [unload on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/unload).