# How to show javascript warning , if user click on link which will open in new window?

Tags: jquery, xhtml, usability, accessibility, screen-readers

How to show this type of reminder warning to user (mainly i need this for screen reader user), if user click on link which will open in new window?

Is my wording ok, please suggest if it can be better ? I want to show this message for any link of website or file like PDF, DOC etc. which is opening in new window?

Sometime user clicks mistakenly so i want to give another reminder.

I'm already using jquery so how to show like this warning box using jquery?

[alt text http://shup.com/Shup/308607/warning.gif](http://shup.com/Shup/308607/warning.gif)

Answer (score 2):

use the onbeforeunload event on window. check [How do you prevent a webpage from navigating away in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821011/how-do-you-prevent-javascript-page-from-navigating-away)

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  return "Are you sure you want to navigate away?";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If what you mean are links that have the *target* property set to *_blank*, you may do the following:

```
$("a[target='_blank']").click(
    function(){
        return confirm("Are you sure?");
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

In new window? I don’t know if I understood what you really want, but I believe the screenshot you captured is a notification triggered on `unload` event—if you use jQuery, check [jQuery’s `.unload()`](http://api.jquery.com/unload/).

Answer (score -1):

Add a click event to all a tags that have a target attribute that is _blank. The click event will display the confirmation dialog.