# How to use JS/jquery to confirm when navigating away from page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to give an alert confirm dialog box when users try to navigate away...I have the following code but it doesn't quite work...

```
    jQuery(window).unload(function() {
        var yes = confirm("You're about to end your session, are you sure?");
        if (yes) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;   
        }
    });
```

The popup comes up fine but when I click "NO", it still navigates away...

Thanks for looking...

Comment: You should look at the example on the [MDN doc for onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.onbeforeunload), there's a compatible function for what you're looking for.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

No need for JQuery:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "You're about to end your session, are you sure?";
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/4fNCh/

Comment: Perfect! this works a charm...I will mark it correct when time allows..Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to add this solution to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821011/how-do-you-prevent-javascript-page-from-navigating-away too?

Comment: @Arnout Engelen Done :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821011/how-do-you-prevent-javascript-page-from-navigating-away/7296750#7296750

Comment: I don't understand how this works... Won't that string always evaluate to `true`, making that function simply `return true` all the time?

Comment: It's returning a string dude. Where do you see it being evaluated?

Comment: Yes, it just returns a string.  That is because of the special behavior of the onbeforeunload event.  If you return a string it automatically displays that string in confirm-like dialog.

Comment: @JesseHallett: Firefox doesn't display that string.

Comment: For some reason I get "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved." instead of what I write. FF 39

Comment: @ShawnRebelo this is a known FF4 issue for a few years now, with a lot of argument on "its a feature not a bug" meeting "its a terrible feature, revert it" meeting "wontfix" : https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=641509

Comment: however chrome doesnt support this feature ...see link https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5349061406228480

Answer (score 3):

this does not work on firefox , on IE and chrome the above works fine.

we can try on firefox

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return confirm("You're about to end your session, are you sure?");
}
```

But this presents 2 dialogue boxes one with above message and one with generic message which looks dirty