# page.js library: how to enable onbeforeunload?

Tags: javascript, url-routing, single-page-application, page.js

I'm building a single-page application using [page.js](https://github.com/visionmedia/page.js/) as the router.  The default [window.onbeforeunload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925251/trigger-an-event-when-user-navigates-away) event doesn't seem to fire when changing pages within the SPA.  How can I implement something similar, allowing me to selectively cancel the page transition if the user decides not to proceed? (i.e. "your changes are not saved: ok to discard changes?")

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the address bar from changing and effectively stop the page processing, inside the `show` function, set `context.handled = false`.  This stops the `pushState` action within page.js, preventing the address bar from changing.

Example:

```
page('/prevent-access', (context, next) => { context.handled = false }) // Prevents URL change to this page.
```