# In Angular 9, how do you implement an onblur handler for a page?

Tags: angular, event-handling, angular9, onblur

I want to set an `onblur` event handler in my Angular 9 app for when someone leaves the page.  My page in question is mapped to a single component that has this ...

```js
export class HotComponent implements OnInit {
  ...

  onBlur(): void {
    console.log("on blur called !!!");
  }
```

In the template, I set this ...

```html
<div (blur)="onBlur()">
  <div>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

But when I navigate away from the browser window where this page is loaded and come back, I notice the `onblur` handler hasn't been called.  What's the proper way to implement the `onblur` event handler for a page in Angular 9?

Comment: A div by default doesn't even receive focus, thus `blur` is going to be useless. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504139/div-onblur-function) for more information. I think you might be looking for `window.onbeforeunload`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925251/trigger-an-event-when-user-navigates-away) for details. And the most upvoted answer about `HostListener` is exactly how you would watch for this event.

Answer (score 5):

Angular has something called `HostListener`, you need to use it!

```js
 /**
   * Blur
   * @param eventName 'focusout' is the key
   * @param arguments of type '$event'
   */
  @HostListener('focusout', ['$event'])
  onFocusout(event) {
    // your logic goes here
    console.log('on blur called'); // This will get printed on blur
  }
```

Comment: This seems to work when I click on a different tab in my browser, but when I switch to a different application (using Cmd + tab on a Mac), it is not called (at least on Firefox).

Comment: When you use Cmd + tab, you need to understand that the browser gets the first instantiation not the tab in which you are working. Once that is done, you need to write your logic, if the browser is forefront then hostlistener will work, if the host itself is not in focus it wont work right?

Comment: I'm not quite understanding.  Where do I need to apply the code you supplied or what other code do I need to add to trigger the onblur event on hte page when someone navigates away using (for example) Cmd + tab?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look into the [`onbeforeunload` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload). The `onblur` event isn't really designed to support your usecase because it targets the state change of an element. What you're attempting to do is intercept a history change on the browser.

> The onbeforeunload property of the WindowEventHandlers mixin is the EventHandler for processing beforeunload events. These events fire when a window is about to unload its resources. At this point, the document is still visible and the event is still cancelable.

As outlined by the other replies, you can add an event listener [via Angular's @HostListener annotation](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener):

```js
@HostListener('window:beforeunload')
foo() {
  // Do something here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two Issues will fix your problem. Add `tabindex="0"` to your `DIV` then handle the events below

```
<!-- language: html -->
// 1
<div  (blur)="onBlur()">  // tabindex="0" gets inserted by HostBinding
// recommend you use an input vs. DIV when user is entering data
```

the second issue is because there are `two events happening` as a result of your navigation you need to handle both. For firefox look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusout_event) for the eventname. Once you import `HostListener` & `HostBinding`

```
<!-- language: typescript -->
// 2
import { Component, HostListener, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
```

1. Handle the `focus event` both focus in and `blur` for exit
2. Handle the `blur event` as you want

---

```
<!-- language: typescript -->
// 3              -- you should be good :)
export class HotComponent { 

focusOutFunction() {
 console.log('focusOutFunction called');
 .. your logic here
 }

focusFunction() {
 console.log('focusFunction called');
 ..
 }

blurFunction()
 {
  console.log('blur called');
  ..
 }

   // you dont need to manually add it to HTML if you do this.
   @HostBinding('attr.tabindex') tabindex = '0';
}
```

---

*Another* option 2: if you have want to handle focusOut

```
  <!-- language: html -->
  <input tabindex="0" type="text" (focusout)="onFocusOutEvent($event)" />
```

---

```
  // in your component explicitly handle the event 
  onFocusOutEvent(event: any){
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }
```

A [simple working sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-focusinout-event-txcyda?devtoolsheight=33&embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html) with the events working for me, Please see console log below pic... it works. Can you please disable all your plugins and try.

[image: Picture with the console events clearly]

Comment: Regarding your first solution, I assume one of those "onFocus" functions should be named somethign else b/c you can't have two fucntisons named the same with the same signature.  Anyway, I changed one to "onFocus2", but not only do they not get called when I Cmd+tab away from the browser and return, they don't get called, when I click on another tab and return to the original tab. (Testing on Mac Firefox)

Comment: Thats correct, I wrote it to give you an idea  on how to _capture_ and _distinguish_ the various events.

Comment: I updated the sample for you, and added a working skeleton on stackblitz with the console to show you I can see the events. Please turn off your plugins and try again

Answer (score -1):

`onBlur` and `onFocus` won't get applied on `div` directly

Anyway, to solve your issue you can just add an `EventListener` on `visibilitychange` in your `app.component` or any other component's constructor.

```js
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", () => {
  if (document.hidden) {
    console.log("Browser tab is on blur")
  } else {
    console.log("Browser tab is on focus")
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm on Firefox, and this logic seems to work when I click on a different Firefox tab.  But when I select another application and bring that application to the forefront of my desktop, the logic isn't getting called.