# onBeforeUnload handler says null in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

my web-app has this:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
    if(unSavedChanges == true)
    {
        return 'You have unsaved changes';
    }
    return null;
});
```

this works fine in Safari and Firefox (with the exception that firefox does not show my custom message in it's onBeforeUnload dialog). However on IE 8 on Windows 7, it always shows the onBeforeUnload notification, specifically if there are no unsaved changes, it would just say "null". How can I prevent IE from showing onBeforeUnload notification when user has saved everything and wants to navigate away?

as per Jon's suggestion, I have removed the `return null` line, the code now reads

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
   if(unSavedChanges == true)
   {
       return 'You have unsaved changes';
   }
});
```

Comment: The second block if code is already the solution, which works correctly, right? 

To me it's honestly a little confusing if we edit the question so that we cannot make out on first sight which code has problems and which one doesn't.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Remove the `return null` line and it should be fine (in Javascript `null` and `undefined` are different things).

By the way, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) says that for maximum compatibility you should be accepting an `event` parameter and setting `event.returnValue` as well.

Comment: doesn't fix it on IE8, checking on IE9

Comment: @ishaq: Works for me in IE9 (configured with "Browser Mode: IE 8" using the developer tools). Can you post the exact code that's not working?

Comment: strange, doesn't work for me on IE9 either. I have updated my question to include the updated code (basically I only removed `return null` as per your suggestion)

Comment: @ishaq: Still [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/h3QWL/) with IE9, both in IE8 and IE9 mode.

Comment: you are right, my bad! this javascript is part of a rails application and after going through the assets pipeline, the code ends up looking like this: `return unsavedChanges ? "You have unsaved changes":null;`

Comment: I'll see what I can do about it, may be I'll put this particular JS snippet into application.js to prevent it from going through assets pipeline

Comment: putting it in application.js still compresses it, googling on how to exclude it

Comment: turned off assets compression, is fixed

Answer (score 0):

I use normal javascript for this and works fine

```
function setConfirmUnload(on) {
     window.onbeforeunload = (on) ? unloadMessage : null;
}

function unloadMessage() {
     return 'Please stay on the page';
}
```

Comment: this will not work, it sets onbeforeunload depending on the value of `on`, and once it's set, it will always fire. the requirement is to check inside onbeforeunload to see if there are unsaved changes.

Comment: It should work, if he binds the `setConfirmUnload` function to the onchange event of the textfield. This way the onbeforeunload function is removed, when the textfield is cleared.