# How to prevent IE11 pop up (Are you sure you want to leave this page)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

I am working on a page that I have nothing to type but a dropdown to select, but in IE11 when I try to move on to the next page, it will pop up the message. I would like to prevent this pop up from happening. So I just wonder what is the default behavior of that pop up in IE11(As it does not appear in either Chrome or Firefox) and how to prevent the pop up

Comment: that *"popup"* sounds very much like the onbeforeunload popup. Are you sure you aren't using the onbeforeunload callback somewhere within your code?

Comment: ↑↑↑  Please check: `alert(window.onbeforeunload);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more important question to ask is: "Why IE11 is popping up that alert?".

Are you leaving a secure page for an insecure one? I.e. make sure to call the secure booking API, or let the browser choose, by not explicitly specifying the protocol:

```
var url = '//api.booking_site.url/api_endpoint';
```

This will call either the secure or insecure version of the url depending if you're currently browsing a secure or insecure site.

If you just want to get rid of the pop-up, assuming the pop-up you mention is an alert box, you can overwrite `alert`:

```
window.alert = function() { return true; }
```

Answer (score 5):

This looks like it's a result of the return value from onbeforeunload. Apparently, instead of returning null you should return nothing.

See also [onBeforeUnload handler says null in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11793996/onbeforeunload-handler-says-null-in-ie)