# "Are you sure you want to leave this page?" message in web browser windows forms c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, browser

I made a program in c # using .NET and Windows Forms. The program must navigate through some web pages and display them on the screen, but when I access certain pages I receive the message in the image below. I tried just about everything I found on the net (searched on Google) and have not found something that works. I think it has something to do with `onbeforeunload`, but I'm not sure.

I already checked discussion on this topic or anything like that on the site.

[image]

Comment: The means `onbeforeunload` is returning something other than `null`.

Comment: Do you have control over these pages the user needs to visit?

Comment: Did you set the "Silent" property on the Web Browser control? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752074(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22535881/how-to-prevent-ie11-pop-up-are-you-sure-you-want-to-leave-this-page

Comment: I don't have control over the pages they come from a web search .I will test the silent property I haven't tried that .

Comment: when I try webBrowser1.Silent = true; i get this error : 'System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser' does not contain a definition for 'Silent' and no extension method 'Silent' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the Visual Studio web browser control you should check your application for memory leaks.  From performing memory testing on many WinForm applications I have discovered that the web browser control is the cause of rather large memory leaks.  I realize that this does not answer you question but it is something you should consider.