# Fire javascript function when user confirms 'Leave Page'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the code below to fire a `confirmExit()` function when the user tries to leave the page:

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
function confirmExit(){
    return "Are you sure you want to exit this page?";
}
```

Furthermore:

The page also fires AJAX functions to update a database 'on the fly'. As a result, when the user leaves the page, I need to delete all that 'on the fly' data.

Is it possible to call a javascript function when the user clicks the 'Leave Page' button?

Comment: have you seen this discussion? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821011/how-do-you-prevent-javascript-page-from-navigating-away

Answer (score 5):

You can try to use [`window.onunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onunload):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    return "Are you sure?";
}
window.onunload = function () {
    console.log("Too bad. Goodbye.");
}
```

`window.onunload` will be fired only when user clicks "Leave this page" button.

If you want to do something if user clicks "Cancel" you can try the following approach:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("Great decision!");
        }, 200);
    }, 1);
    return "Are you sure?";
}
```

The first [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout) puts your code to the event queue. It will be fired just after confirm box is closed. Second `setTimeout` will be fired after some time if page is not closed too soon.

For those who are doing some XHR `onunload`: make sure to use synchronous approach to complete your requests before the page is closed. E.g. use `async: false` in `jQuery.ajax` or `XMLHttpRequest.open(method, url, false)` in plain js.

Comment: @proPhet did you try what I am suggesting? Maybe I need to clarify this a bit more?