# Detect if the user clicked the “back” button - Mobile Browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, back-button-control

I have very weird requirement.

Requirement says: **On Product detail page,when product image is opened in lightbox then on pressing `back` button on browser in mobile, product detail page shall be shown, not previous page i.e. product grid page**

So, i thought of searching that how to handle back button in cross browsers. Some solutions worked in Desktop browsers but none worked in `Mobile Browsers`

I tried below solution:

```
window.onload = function () {
if (typeof history.pushState === "function") {
    history.pushState("jibberish", null, null);
    window.onpopstate = function () {
        history.pushState('newjibberish', null, null);
        // Handle the back (or forward) buttons here
        // Will NOT handle refresh, use onbeforeunload for this.
    };
}
else {
    var ignoreHashChange = true;
    window.onhashchange = function () {
        if (!ignoreHashChange) {
            ignoreHashChange = true;
            window.location.hash = Math.random();
            // Detect and redirect change here
            // Works in older FF and IE9
            // * it does mess with your hash symbol (anchor?) pound sign
            // delimiter on the end of the URL
        }
        else {
            ignoreHashChange = false;
        }
    };
  }
};
```

Also tried this:

```
 if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {

$(window).on('popstate', function() {
  var hashLocation = location.hash;
  var hashSplit = hashLocation.split("#!/");
  var hashName = hashSplit[1];

  if (hashName !== '') {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if (hash === '') {
      alert('Back button was pressed.');
    }
  }
});
```

**Tried this as well**

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
        var e = e || window.event;
        var msg = ""
        $("#blueimp-gallery").hide();
        // For IE and Firefox
        if (e) {
            e.returnValue = msg;
        }

        // For Safari / chrome
        return msg;
     };
```

Comment: What are your browser requirements? history.pushState is available in most mobile browsers except Opera Mini.

Comment: All mobile browser. I really dnt care about Opera. And if you think that it is available in all browsers then how shall i hide lightbox by pressing back button and then after closing lightbox backbutton shall behave as default behaviour

Answer (score 0):

As you've no doubt learned, `onbeforeunload` provides a way to simply cancel the navigation event (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18115932/957950) for a good place to start), but it doesn't always work the way you want in all browsers (many just show a confirmation popup no matter what you do, for security reasons). Give this a shot first if you haven't already; I don't see any attempts at cancellation in your current code example, just history manipulation.

Failing that, using hash routing might help with this - preferably via a library that manages the URL hash as unique view routes (baked into Angular, React, etc) and pushes changes to the `history` for you. Giving the modal state a unique URL (which typically wouldn't be done in my experience) means that going 'back' would just close the modal instead of reloading the page.