# Angular 4 router: prevent direct browser navigation

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular4-router

How can I convince the Angular 4 router to disable direct browser navigation within my app?

I have looked into the router hooks `CanActivate` and `CanDeactivate` and implemented them but `CanDeactivate` does not fire at all when using direct browser navigation.

I can use `CanActivate` to prevent the url but only after the app reboots, which takes time and undesired changes in the browser window.

I want to be able to catch the direct browser navigation BEFORE the app reboots.

In case this helps:
I want to disallow direct browser navigation altogether, so I don't need a solution that allows certain urls and disables others.

Here's my router definition:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [RouteGuardService] },
  { path: 'users', component: UsersMainComponent, canActivate: [RouteGuardService] },
  { path: 'vendors', component: VendorMainComponent, canActivate: [RouteGuardService] },
  { path: 'invoices', component: InvoicesMainComponent, canActivate: [RouteGuardService] },
  { path: 'offers' , component: EsdMainComponent, canActivate: [RouteGuardService] },
  { path: 'settings' , component: SettingsMainComponent, canActivate: [RouteGuardService] },
  // Callback MUST not be route guard protected.
  { path: 'callback' , component: CallbackComponent },
  { path: 'createvendor' , component: CreateVendorsComponent, canActivate: [RouteGuardService] },
  { path: 'customerdashboard' , component: CustomerDashboardComponent, canActivate: [RouteGuardService] },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [RouteGuardService]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Can you provide your router code?

Answer (score 7):

The following solution is not an Angular based one. As Maximus explained in his answer this is a browser issue and therefor the solution must be browser based.

This solution is derived from an answer on this site ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821011/how-do-you-prevent-a-webpage-from-navigating-away-in-javascript/18115932#18115932)) I have written a little (typescript) service with the following three methods:

```
  private preventNavigation(): void {
    const location = window.document.location;
    const originalHashValue = location.hash;

    window.setTimeout(() => {
      location.hash = 'preventNavigation' + (9999 * Math.random());
      location.hash = originalHashValue;
    }, 0);
  }

  public disableBrowserNavigation(): void {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.preventNavigation, false);
    window.addEventListener('unload', this.preventNavigation, false);
  }

  public enableBrowserNavigation(): void {
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.preventNavigation);
    window.removeEventListener('unload', this.preventNavigation);
  }
```

This works fine but I'm still open to other solutions.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I convince the Angular 4 router to disable direct browser
>   navigation within my app?

Angular can't do that because that's not something controlled by Angular. When you go the address bar and type in address and then press enter a browser loads a new page. It can be an Angular application or can be any other application. It's a browser functionality. Angular controls navigation only **inside the app** when you click on the `routerLink`.

You could try to use [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) but it has its limitations.

Comment: onbeforeunload by itself doesn't work in my case because of the limitations you mentioned. However, going deeper in that direction has led to a possible solution. I'll check it out and if it works will share it as an answer. I understand and agree with your argument that it is out of Angular's control because it is a browser functionality.