# Adding additional function to exit page popup message

Tags: javascript, popup, warnings, exit

I want to add an additional function to a basic plain javascript exit page popup. Basically, I have my page set up so when a user tries to exit the page a message will appear saying "do you really want to leave" with the options "OK" and "Cancel". I want to set it up so when the user clicks OK it will redirect them to another website. I don't have a lot of experience coding so I'm not sure if this is possible. Here is the code that I'm using:

```
<h1 id="home">Warn before leaving the page</h1>

<script>
// Warning before leaving the page (back button, or outgoinglink)
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
   return "Do you really want to leave?";
   //if we return nothing here (just calling return;) then there will be no pop-up question at all
   //return;
};
</script>

<a href="http://google.com/</a>
```

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is something you should avoid doing because it is bad user experience. Also this is a repeat of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821011/prevent-a-webpage-from-navigating-away-using-javascript).

Comment: I won't be using it in a published website, I just want to experiment with it. Also the post you linked is showing how to code the exit warning but I want to know if I can get it so the code opens up another webpage on exit.