# Bring back user to same browser tab trying to switch tab

Tags: javascript, browser-tab

I need to know is there a way in JavaScript through which we could prevent user from switching tab, After he press NO against message "Do you want to switch tab?".

I have a way to know that browser tab is changed by using blur.

I have seen browser extension API's having those functions.

But I really need to how can we bring back user trying to switch current tab. Some event before blur or something similar.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/unload/ or `window.onbeforeunload` - AFAIK there isn't a way to prevent a user from navigating away entirely, let alone bringing them back again. Why would you want to do this anyway? This would be a terrible user experience.

Comment: User is attending test.

Comment: See here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821011/prevent-a-webpage-from-navigating-away-using-javascript

Comment: I can gladly tell that your JavaScript sandbox does NOT have active control over browser tabs

Comment: So @Michel it means answer is "No way" :(

Comment: @spooner onbeforeunload works only for closing tab or browser.