# How do I prevent a browser page refresh in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, page-refresh

I would like to prevent an HTML page refresh (given a variable `refreshMode != 1`):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
   if(refreshMode == 1){
     return;
   }else{
     // don't do it!
    e.preventDefault();
   }
};
```

I have tried `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()`, but neither appears to be preventing the refresh from submit the request.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: I have never done this by this way but there is others like using Ajax. If you are trying to do a one-page website I recommend looking reactjs navigation.

Comment: did you try `return false` ?

Comment: Try `return true`: https://jsfiddle.net/ydbnuvt1/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent a webpage from navigating away using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821011/prevent-a-webpage-from-navigating-away-using-javascript)

Comment: e.preventDefault(); should work if you are handling the submit of a form through "onSubmit()", you doing that?

Comment: Dominik, seemed to work first time I tried only.

Comment: Will, this works but is there a way to prevent the popup prompt? If I cancel it doesn't refresh but I want that to be the default behavior, without being prompted.

Comment: Menawer, no. This is when the user hit refresh on browser button i.e. F5

Comment: luk2302, yes this works but still I get the popup. I want to prevent the prompt, too... so I don't have to click cancel to prevent refresh. If refreshMode is 0, then don't prompt and don't refresh.

Answer (score 2):

Set a return value in additiont o preventing default. You cannot change the prompt text (that used to be possible), and you cannot prevent the prefresh if the user confirms on the prompt.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event

```js
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
  // Cancel the event as stated by the standard.
  event.preventDefault();
  // Chrome requires returnValue to be set.
  event.returnValue = '';
});
```

Comment: Ok, yes that works, but I don't want the prompt. If refreshMode is off, then don't refresh and don't prompt user.

Comment: Sorry that's not possible in the browser.

Comment: @Jim that is obviously not possible, do you think it is a good idea to let spam / ad sites trap you one their site preventing you from leaving it?

Comment: @luk2302 a refresh click isn't meant to take you away, though.

Comment: How about we give the pop up but don't let the user select Reload button, is this possible? Is it possible to prompt user that tasks are pending so you cannot refresh the page?