# Android Back button handler react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener

I am trying to stop my application from returning to the previous screen when a modal is present. This currently closes the modal but also exits the existing page and returns home.

Any ideas on how to stop this from happening ?

```js
document.addEventListener('backbutton', function(e) {
  if(modalIsOpen === true) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsOpen(false);
  }
});
```

Comment: You might be looking for the `onunload` or `onbeforeunload` .. possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821011/prevent-a-webpage-from-navigating-away-using-javascript

Comment: Still trying to figure it out currently just using the code I originally used but it doesn't function like I would have wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I found with help from Ionic

```
document.addEventListener('ionBackButton', (ev) => {
            ev.detail.register(10, (processNextHandler) => {
                if (modalIsOpen === true) {
                    setIsOpen(false);
                    console.log('Handler was called!');
                    processNextHandler();
                }
            });
    });
```